# How to make property getters queries by default in Enterprise Architect

Tags: enterprise-architect

When setting a class attribute as a property in Enterprise Architect (Property checkbox in the attribute's window), is there a way to tag the getter as a query (IsQuery checkbox in the method's window advanced tab) by default? It's not done by default and thus I have to do it manually for every property getter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's an option to set for this, but you might try the Template Package.

This special package is used to serve as a template for all new elements, so it might set the isQuery property as well.

If that doesn't work you can make a little script as workaround to set it for every getter.

The property `EA.Method.IsQuery` is available in the API.
So a VBScript script to update this could be something like

```
option explicit

!INC Local Scripts.EAConstants-VBScript

'
' Script Name: Set IsQuery Getter
' Author: Geert Bellekens
' Purpose: sets the IsQuery property to true for all operations in the selected package with stereotype "property get"
' Date: 2016-01-22
'
sub main
    dim selectedPackage as EA.Package
    set selectedPackage = Repository.GetTreeSelectedPackage()
    dim element as EA.Element
    dim operation as EA.Method
    for each element in selectedPackage.Elements
        for each operation in element.Methods
            if operation.Stereotype = "property get" then
                operation.IsQuery = true
                operation.Update
            end if
        next
    next
end sub

main
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at it.

Comment: Template Package doesn't seem to work, any new property you create has the getter without the IsQuery tag even if you copy the property from one that has it. I'll have to look at the scripting, but since I haven't done any yet that might take some time.

Comment: I added a small example script to my answer. I'm just not sure about the stereotype on "getter" operations.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I indeed had to change the stereotype from "get" to "property get", but otherwise it worked perfectly fine! And by the way thanks also for the webinar (http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/resources/webinar/partners/scripting/scripting-introduction-bellekens.html), it helped me figure out how to use the script in EA and run it from the project browser :).

Comment: You're welcome. I've updated to answer with the corrected stereotype.